# Que veut dire « une ligne de crête » - sens politique ou social et non pas géologique ?

Tags: sens, expressions, traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

Quel est le sens de la phrase « une ligne de crête », non pas dans le sens géologique du terme mais plutôt dans un sens politique ?

Je l'ai entendu  sur France Infos ce soir. C'était dans le cadre d'une discussion sur la nouvelle politique d'immigration qu'a entamée Emmanuel Macron. Désolé, mais il ne m'est pas possible d'être plus précis - je conduisais, alors je n'écoutais qu'à moité.

J'avais l'impression qu'elle voulait dire quelque chose comme quoi Macron prenait une position au-delà de laquelle il ne pouvait plus aller.

Comment: Une bon exemple de l'emploi de l'expression par Raphaël Enthoven dans [son interview](https://www.franceinter.fr/emissions/l-invite-de-8h20-le-grand-entretien/l-invite-de-8h20-le-grand-entretien-01-novembre-2019) de ce matin, la façon dont il file la métaphore éclaire bien le sens.

Comment: Merci - mais a quelle minute a peu pres?

Comment: Effectivement, c'est une utilisation parfaite dans le contexte dont je parlais. Je pense qu'une traduction dans la sale langue barbare de l'anglo-saxon ( :-) ) serait quelque chose dans le genre "is on a knife-edge between...". Si tu désire donner une réponse à la question, je la marquerais comme étant la bonne, à cause de la réponse mais aussi à cause de l'aide que tu m'a apportée dans la formulation correcte de ma question.

Comment: `je ne suis pas ici pour « faire du chiffre » ... aider, progresser et faire progresser` - tout à fait - sur DBA.SE, la plupart de mes contributions sont des commentaires ou des revues - mais il est gentil d'être gentil et tu m'as été d'une grande aide pour comprendre le "Zeitgeist" de FR.SE ce qui est plus utile à la longue qu'une simple réponse à une seule question.Néanmoins, effectivement la réponse de @aCOSwt est la bonne (je n'avais pas vu la phrase "knife-edge" dans sa réponse initiale). Je vais marquer la sienne avec la flèche!En tout cas, merci encore de ton aide et à bientôt j'espère.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je pense que l'anglais utiliserait : ***tightrope*** (la corde raide du funambule)

Maintenant la traduction mot à mot de *crest line* ne serait pas absurde tant, même si tu ne veux pas du sens géologique, c'est bien le sens géologique que l'image véhicule :

On va d'un sommet à un autre en suivant un chemin très étroit et un pas de travers vous fait basculer franchement d'un côté ou de l'autre (ce que l'on essayait justement d'éviter) BinGBaDHaBENG!

Si on veut insister sur l'étroitesse de cette *ligne de crête* (en géologie on la dirait aiguë) et, par là, indiquer le peu de marge de manœuvre dont on dispose, on peut aussi parler, comme le suggère @jlliagre en commentaires, de *fil du rasoir*, c'est le ***razor's blade*** ou le ***knife-edge*** que l'anglais utiliserait dans le même sens.

Pour ce qui est de la position au-delà de laquelle un parti politique ne peut aller (en est-il une ?) je crois que le français préférerait parler de *ligne rouge* que l'on traduirait mot à mot en anglais.

---

Merci à [Laure-so-Écoute-nous](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/358/laure-so-%C3%89coute-nous) pour la communication de cet usage de *ligne de crête* par [Raphaël Enthoven](https://www.franceinter.fr/emissions/l-invite-de-8h20-le-grand-entretien/l-invite-de-8h20-le-grand-entretien-01-novembre-2019)

Comment: Il y a aussi une peu de **fil du rasoir** dans cette ligne de crête.

Comment: @jlliagre : Oui Absolument. Suggestion ajoutée. Merci. Cela dit... peut-être les journalistes anglais cherchent-ils ici des tuyaux pour décrire la situation de leur PM... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Cette réponse est basée sur une première formulation de la question du demandeur dans laquelle il était question de lui fournir une base de correspondance des termes avec l'anglais, cette langue lui étant apparemment plus habituelle. En supposant que cela soit toujours son souhait, bien que non stipulé dans sa nouvelle formulation, ma réponse demeure inchangée.

D'après le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ligne_de_cr%C3%AAte) ce terme a deux sens ;

1/    (Géographie)
 Ligne formée par les faîtes des montagnes ou coteaux d’une contrée.

2/ (Figuré) Frontière entre deux états sur laquelle il est malaisé de rester sans basculer d’un côté.

- À la différence de ceux de Panama, dont bon nombre relevaient de la fraude, du détournement, du recyclage ou du blanchiment, les « Paradise Papers » nous parlent de l’art de surfer sur la **ligne de crête de la légalité**.  (Érik Emptaz, Pervers Papers, Le Canard Enchaîné, 8 novembre 2017, page 1)

L'usage figuré attesté dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie réfère à des expressions dans lesquelles sont utilisés uniquement le verbe « se tenir » et dont les sens sont suffisamment différents.

3/ ([Dictionnaire de l'Ac.](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/CR%C3%8ATE?options=motExact))
 Fig. **Se tenir sur la crête**, **sur les crêtes**, **sur la ligne de crête** : prendre une position dominante et, souvent, exposée.

Dans le cas du sens littéral « 2/ » il s'agit  de traduire par  « [ridgeline](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ridgeline) » en anglais. Il n'existe apparemment pas un équivalent figuré pour « ridgeline ». « Ligne de crête » dans le sens  figuré correspond en anglais aux expressions "**tight rope**", "**thin line**", and "**fine line**", équivalentes les unes aux autres.

Il n'y a donc aucune idée  de « ligne dans le sable » mais il est question de « position difficile qui demande de quelqu'un des manœuvres habiles » ;  lorsque l'on ajoute les termes traditionnels aux expressions anglaises (tread/walk a thin line), on peut dire en français « **marcher sur des charbons ardents** » ou « **marcher sur des épines** ». L'expression « **marcher sur des œufs** » est légèrement différente et ne convient pas exactement.

(TLFi) Marcher (comme) sur des œufs : Se mouvoir avec une précaution pouvant frôler le ridicule.

On ne trouve  ce terme au sens figuré « 2/ » en français que depuis récemment il y a de fortes chances pour qu'il vienne directement de l'anglais.

http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/ligne%20de%20cr%C3%AAte/fr-fr/ (Le Parisien)
https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%AAte (TLFi, II A. 1.)
[https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/CRÊTE?options=motExact](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/CR%C3%8ATE?options=motExact) (Dictionnaire Ac.)

Si le verbe « se tenir » était utilisé dans l'expression contenant « ligne de crête » la signification est différente et il faut traduire par d'autres termes que « tightrope ».

D'après la définition de l'Ac. on peut traduire par « **forefront** ».

- to hold a forefront position